# MaTeX no longer working after upgrade

Tags: matex

My institution has recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and to Mathematica 11.3 and I'm guessing various other packages have been upgraded alongside this. I have the latest MaTeX version downloaded (1.7.4) and the GhostScript version installed is 9.25 (as ascertained by running `gs --version`, also `gs` is in the usual place: `/usr/bin/gs`). However when I run

```
Needs["PacletManager`"]
PacletInstall["~/Downloads/MaTeX-1.7.4.paclet"]
Needs["MaTeX`"]
```

It tells me

```
/usr/bin/gs is either not working or is not a command line version of Ghostscript
Please configure Ghostscript using ConfigureMaTeX["Ghostscript"->"path to gs executable"]
```

Upon running

```
ConfigureMaTeX["Ghostscript"->"/usr/bin/gs"]
```

I get the same error. `gs` is a command line version, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Please download the troubleshooting notebook (linked at the end of [this page](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html)), evaluate it, and e-mail it to me. Instructions are within the notebook.

Comment: I went ahead with the answer before receiving your response e-mail as I need to log off for today. Let me know if you think my hypothesis is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** MaTeX 1.7.0 and later do not have this issue. Restarting Mathematica after upgrading will fix the problem.

---

After receiving the troubleshooting notebook from OP in e-mail, I believe this is what happened:

The problem encountered by the OP only affects MaTeX versions earlier than 1.7.0. The OP probably had such an old version. After upgrading the paclet to 1.7.4, the OP immediately tried to re-load MaTeX with `Needs` instead of `Get`, without restarting Mathematica. `Needs` however does not re-load an already loaded package. The package was updated only on the disk, but not in-memory, thus the issue persisted.

Using `Get`, or just quitting the kernel, fixes it.

I have updated [the instruction](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX) to suggest using `Get` instead of `Needs`. Hopefully, others won't fall in the same trap.

---

What exactly fails in MaTeX on Linux systems prior to version 1.7.0?

MaTeX uses `RunProcess` to call Ghostscript and pdflatex. Both depend on [zlib](https://zlib.net/). Mathematica ships an older version of zlib on Linux, and its startup script sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to Mathematica's own library directory where this zlib is located.  This means that not only Mathematica, but also any other program launched by Mathematica will try to use this old zlib. However, programs shipped with recent Linux distributions require a newer zlib, and will fail when dynamically linking against Mathematica's copy.

This is what happens:

```
In[]:= RunProcess[{"/usr/bin/gs", "--version"}]

Out[]= <|"ExitCode" -> 1, "StandardOutput" -> "", 
 "StandardError" -> 
     "/usr/bin/gs: /opt/mathematica/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1: \
      version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)"|>
```

The workaround is to temporarily clear `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running these programs. This is best achieved with the [`ProcessEnvironment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProcessEnvironment.html) option of [`RunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html): preserve everything in the environment ([`GetEnvironment`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GetEnvironment.html)), *except* `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Unlike `SetEnvironment`, this method is safe. `SetEnvironment` would affect *all* programs launched by Mathematica, including some of its own components.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Most impressive was that you diagnosed the version change without me doing much.